# ORDER BY after a WHERE with a escape_string within a sql SELECT

Tags: sql, where-clause, mysql-real-escape-string, sql-order-by

I have the following select query, where I need to add an ORDER BY topic_id DESC. How can I add it?

```
$sql = "SELECT  
    top_id,
    top_cat,
            COUNT(top_id) AS topic
FROM
    topics
WHERE
    top_cat = ". mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

I cannot add the ORDER BY right before the last semicolon (;) since it will get an error and, of course, it cannot be placed right before the quotes ("). I also tried to place it before WHERE but again, shows errors later when I introduce if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Concat* the " order by topic_id desc" before the semi-colon, just like you concat the ID. If that's what you were doing when you say "you can't place it right before the semicolon" I don't know why not.

It's easier to diagnose code errors if you show the code that created the errors.

Comment: I'm sorry about that! Here is what I'm trying now: $sql = "SELECT  topic_id,topic_subject,topic_date,topic_cat,COUNT(topic_id) AS topic FROM topics WHERE topic_cat = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) ORDER BY topic_id DESC;

Comment: You need to concatenate the addition SQL, so `...($_GET['id') . "order by topic_id desc;"` which is what I said in my answer--the same way you're concatenating the id onto the end of the SQL string now.

Comment: and this is the output: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a2349782/public_html/category.php on line 48. Which is the ORDER BY topic_id DESC; line.

Comment: Now it makes sense! THANKS Mr Dave! Now I have to work on how to show them on the output since it's only showing the very first topic only :-/ THANKS!!!!